# Any other bourne shell port on Linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm looking for Linux ports of historic Bourne shell versions (other than [the Heirloom shell](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html), which implements the SVR4/SVID3 level of the shell).  For curiosity and research, I want to dig into the internals of historic shell code.

**Specifically:** I'm looking for historic versions of the **Bourne shell** that have been ported to Linux.  **I'm not** looking for modern reimplementations, "Bourne Compatible shells", "Bourne Again shell", "C-shell/T-C-shell", or "Korn shell".

thanks.
jcyang.

Comment: Why do you want them?  I ask because it might improve the answers you get.

Comment: Do you mean ports of what? Original Version 7 code? There are a ton of bourne-compatible shells: bash, dash, ash, and the one included with BusyBox.

Comment: to Warren:For curiosity and research.I want to dig into the internal of shell^_^

Comment: to Zan Lynx:Only the orignal "bourne shell" descendent are needed.According to wikipedia, dash and ash could be OK...

Comment: i rephrased your question for clarity, hope it's not too far from where you're aiming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate answering with just a link to Wikipedia, but see [Bourne-compatible shells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Bourne_shell_compatible) which does list `ash` and `dash` which were the first two to come to mind for me (that weren't `bash`).

Comment: em..ash and dash would be OK.so any others?

Answer (score 2):

**GNU Bash** is very popular. It is complete, in fact highly extended, and also kind of big and slow, although I'm not sure you would notice on today's zippy CPUs.

**ash** is the native BSD shell. It is smaller, faster, and often installed as /bin/sh even on linux in order to make generic shell scripts run fast. It's a perfectly decent interactive shell EXCEPT that on many linux distros, it is considered non-interactive (the developers probably all use bash) and so the build is deliberately crippled in order to make it even smaller. If you use it interactively, build it from source.

**ksh** and **zsh** are older enhanced shells.

**csh** is ancient and non-posix, and it won't run most shell command files. It is almost always installed out-of-the-box, though, and it might provide some amusement. In particular the ! history substitution, available in bash, was invented here and is kind of neat.

[Wikipedia has a comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_command_shells).

Comment: You should use the wikipedia page to pick out the bourne ("posix") ones. csh is not, of course.

Answer (score 1):

[GNU Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) is a very well-known and frequently used Bourne shell.

Answer (score 1):

It is pre-Bourne, but you might be interested in the [Sixth Edition Thompson shell](http://v6shell.org/).